# Which's the right definition of 'operate'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

Source: p 21, *Criminal Law: The Basics*, 1 ed (2009), by Herring

> THE OPERATING AND SUBSTANTIAL CAUSE TEST
>
> The courts have held that the defendant will have caused a result if
> his or her act was an **operating** and substantial cause of the death. It
> does not need to be shown that the action was the sole cause of
> death, as long as what was done was an **operating** cause of death.
> This means that there may be several **operating** and substantial
> causes of death. This principle has been of particular relevance in
> cases where a defendant has injured the victim, who is taken to
> hospital, where the treatment the victim receives is negligent. The
> courts have tended to say that the defendant’s acts are still an
> **operating** cause. After all, but for his or her actions, the victim
> would not have been suffering injuries that required him or her to
> go to hospital in the first place.

How do you determine/deduce the right definition of **[operating](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/131741?rskey=J024cF&result=2&isAdvanced=false)**?  Does **operate** only mean any cause, criminal or not, that effected a crime, as in 6 and 11? I think that 10 is possible, because this quote discusses criminal law and so could refer only to a cause limited to 'carry[ing] on criminal activities'?

> 6. intr. To perform an operation or series of operations. With (up)on
>
> 10. intr. To carry on criminal activities.
>
> 11. intr. To be in action, to be functioning. Cf. sense 6.

Comment: Please show what thought processes you have used when trying to decide among them, and why those processes have left you unable to choose among these meanings, so that we may better help you to do this in the future. For example, why would #10 be a candidate? Remember, the noun being modified is "cause".

Comment: @TRomano Thanks. I've updated. Better?

Comment: @Law, the operating definition here, from a *layman's* perspective is "*12. to bring about, effect, or produce, as by action or the exertion of force or influence*". But as you know, legalese diverges from plain English in the *specific* meanings of such words, because their senses in the legal sphere have been shaped by precedent, challenges, decisions, and usage, and typically come to have a *specific*, *fixed*, *universally agreed upon* meaning which may bear no or only passing relation to the original definition found plain English (as opposed to legal) dictionaries.

Comment: Also, #10 is really a bogus definition, IMO. The definition is: "to carry on business activities (licit or illicit)". There is no need for the lexicographers to have created separate entries for licit and illicit business activities.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to learn to fish, not to be given a fish...

The passage is about 'causality' and the kinds of causes. The sentences in question all require an adjective that can modify the noun 'cause'. If you attempt to cast each of those meanings into an *adjectival* phrase modifying the word 'cause', you should have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Operating works as an adjective here and has the meaning given in definition 11.

An operating cause of a death is something that is the cause, or one of the causes, at work in making a person die at the time when the death occurs.

If I yelled *boo!* at someone who had a very weak heart due to a heart attack they had previously sufferred, and then the person immediately dropped dead, the law might be concerned with the question of whether the death was caused by the heart disease, my yell, or both. It's easy to imagine a situation in which someone could argue that my yell was a substantial cause, and that my yell was acting to cause the death at the time that the person died.

Suppose, on the other hand, that I had yelled at the person in the same way a year before they died. Someone might say that my yell created a weakness that remained active on the person for the whole period, and was one of the causes of death. If a judge or jury was convinced that the effect of my yelling was no longer at work at the time of death, then my yell would not be seen as a legal cause. It was not in operation at the time of death.

I'm not sure I can explain my entire deductive process, however.